# Undefined Index - Trying to POST a base64 encoded image to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, base64

I am trying to find out where my error is and I am very new to PHP. I am attempting to send an image that is produced from a js function. I am currently running this on localhost until I can work the kinks out. Here are some code snippets.

This is the js code where I POST an image to a php file:

```
$('#send-image-mail-php').click(function() {
                yourDesigner.getProductDataURL(function(dataURL) {
                    $.post("php/send_image_via_mail.php", { base64_image: yourDesigner.getProductDataURL() }, function(data) {
                        if(data) {
                            alert("Mail successfully sent!");
                        }
                        else {            
                        alert("Mail could not be sent!");
                        }
            });
```

this is the php code:

```
<?php

$base64_str = substr($_POST['base64_image'], strpos($_POST['base64_image'], ",")+1);
$to =   'myemail@domain.com';//set here your receiving mail address
$subject =  'Fancy Product Designer Test Email'; //set here the mail subject
$message = '';
$bound_text =   md5(date('r', time()));
$bound =    "--".$bound_text."\r\n";
$bound_last =   "--".$bound_text."--\r\n";

$headers =  "From: myemail@domain.com\r\n";//set here the sending mail address
$headers .=     "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";

$message .=     "If you can see this MIME than your client doesn't accept MIME types!\r\n";
    .$bound;

$message .=     "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
    ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
    ."Email Sent Successfully\r\n" //set here the mail text
    .$bound;

$message .=     "Content-Type: image/png; name=\"mail_product.png\"\r\n"
    ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
    ."Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"mail_product.png\"\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    .chunk_split($base64_str)
    .$bound_last;

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
     echo json_encode(1);
} else {
     echo json_encode(0);
}

?>
```

And here is the error log from my Apache Server, running locally through XAMPP:

```
[Sat Sep 12 00:32:37.790441 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 10748:tid 1920] [client ::1:61515] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: base64_image in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\send_image_via_mail.php on line 6, referer: http://localhost/product-designer.html
[Sat Sep 12 00:32:37.790441 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 10748:tid 1920] [client ::1:61515] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: base64_image in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\send_image_via_mail.php on line 6, referer: http://localhost/product-designer.html
[Sat Sep 12 00:32:37.856441 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 10748:tid 1924] [client ::1:61517] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: base64_image in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\send_image_via_mail.php on line 6, referer: http://localhost/product-designer.html
[Sat Sep 12 00:32:37.856441 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 10748:tid 1924] [client ::1:61517] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: base64_image in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\send_image_via_mail.php on line 6, referer: http://localhost/product-designer.html
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: --- MESSAGE BEGIN ---
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: To: myemail@domain.com
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: Subject: Fancy Product Designer Test Email
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: From: myemail@domain.com
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: MIME-Version: 1.0
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="f6e9b319c244b41ebc6650ef9c316270"
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: 
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: If you can see this MIME than your client doesn't accept MIME types!
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: --f6e9b319c244b41ebc6650ef9c316270
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: 
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: Email sent successfully
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: --f6e9b319c244b41ebc6650ef9c316270
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: Content-Type: image/png; name="mail_product.png"
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: Content-disposition: attachment; file="mail_product.png"
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: 
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: 
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: --f6e9b319c244b41ebc6650ef9c316270--
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: 
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: --- MESSAGE END ---
sendmail: Error writing to C:\xampp\sendmail\debug.log: Authenticating with POP3 server
sendmail: Error during delivery: Connect tim
```

Not sure why the error log cuts off on the last line. I closed and reopened the logs to  make sure that I  didn't catch it writing mid-word.

Also, I was getting an error about $message being undefined as well, but I seemed to have fixed this error by declaring it as '';  with the rest of the  declarations.

Anyways, I've already configured my php.ini files, as well as the sendmail.ini file. I am using gmail to send and receive the email. I entered SMTP as well as POP... I hope that isn't where I went wrong.

Sorry  if this has been posted before. I could really use some insight. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Update: I removed the pop info from sendmail.ini,  and this is the new error. I  could  rip my  hair out:

`[php7:error] [pid 7480:tid 1924] [client ::1:62901] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting end of file in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\php\\send_image_via_mail.php on line 22, referer: http://localhost/product-designer.html`

Comment: what is `getProductDataURL` ?

Comment: It's a custom function used in the product designer that produces the image I'm trying to pass to  the PHP script. Here is the documentation on it:

[link](https://jquerydoc.fancyproductdesigner.com/classes/FancyProductDesigner.html#method_getProductDataURL)

Comment: Another update!

I added an app specific password to my gmail account, and now the  emails send, but the  image is empty, and none of the message text is parsed. Not quite square 1, but still the same issue.